# XSLT, XML: Grouping by attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

Which is the best way to group Elements based on attribute value using XSLT?
Would it be better to use XSLT 2.0 or higher?

Many thank in advance for your help

Thomas

---

Original XML:

```
<transaction>    
  <record type="1" >
    <field number="1" >
        <item >223</item>
    </field>
  </record>

  <record type="14" >
    <field number="1" >
        <item >777</item>
    </field>
  </record>

  <record type="14" >
    <field number="1" >
        <item >555</item>
    </field>
  </record>      
</transaction>
```

---

Result after grouping:

```
<transaction>
  <records type="1" >
      <record type="1" >
        <field number="1" >
            <item >223</item>
        </field>
      </record>
  </records>

  <records type="14" >
      <record type="14" >
        <field number="1" >
            <item >777</item>
        </field>
      </record>

      <record type="14" >
        <field number="1" >
            <item >555</item>
        </field>
      </record>
  </records>
</transaction>
```

Comment: The answer is "yes". If you are able to use XSLT 2.0, then it would almost certainly be better to use it. In this case, you can make use of the `xsl:for-each-group` construct, which makes grouping much easier. So, in this case you would do `<xsl:for-each-group select="record" group-by="@type" />`

Comment: Hi Tim! 
Many thanks for your fast reply. 
I tried it with the following template:
    <xsl:template match="transaction/record">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="record" group-by="@type">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
 
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

The result XML contains just the root element.
Many thanks again for your help.
Thomas

<transaction>         
</transaction>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0, you can use `xsl:for-each-group`, but if you are going to do `<xsl:for-each-group select="record" group-by="@type">` then you must be positioned on the `transaction` record at that point.

Additionally, you will need to make use of `current-group` to get all the `record` elements within the group.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="transaction"> 
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="record" group-by="@type"> 
            <records type="{current-grouping-key()}" >
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
            </records>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="@*|node()"> 
    <xsl:copy> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> 
    </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```