# XSLT, XML: How to disentangle grouped blocks into a flat hierarchy?

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I have the following XML with some Nested elements.
I need please help for converting this XML to a flat hierarchy.

You may would like to take a look at this question as well:
[XSLT, XML: Grouping by attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46693291/xslt-xml-grouping-by-attribute-value)

Thanks in advance for your support.
Thomas

Original XML:

```
<transaction>
  <records type="1" >
      <record type="1" >
        <field number="1" >
            <item >223</item>
        </field>
      </record>
  </records>

  <records type="14" >
      <record type="14" >
        <field number="1" >
            <item >777</item>
        </field>
      </record>

      <record type="14" >
        <field number="1" >
            <item >555</item>
        </field>
      </record>
  </records>

  <record type="200" >
    <field number="1" >
        <item>546</item>
    </field>
  </record>

  <record type="201" >
    <field number="1" >
        <item>123</item>
    </field>
  </record>
</transaction>
```

Target XML:

```
<transaction>    
  <record type="1" >
    <field number="1" >
        <item >223</item>
    </field>
  </record>

  <record type="14" >
    <field number="1" >
        <item >777</item>
    </field>
  </record>

  <record type="14" >
    <field number="1" >
        <item >555</item>
    </field>
  </record> 

  <record type="200" >
    <field number="1" >
        <item>546</item>
    </field>
  </record>

  <record type="201" >
    <field number="1" >
        <item>123</item>
    </field>
  </record>
</transaction>
```

Comment: I have the XLST from Tim's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46693291/xslt-xml-grouping-by-attribute-value

Comment: @ThomasMuller aren't you trying to do the exact opposite?

Comment: Yes, exactly :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
        <transaction>
            <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="//record">
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
        </transaction>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `<xsl:text>` tags are to preserve some of the formatting in the output XML but I don't know if you're interested in that. Feel free to remove them if not.

It works by using a `for-each` to look for elements in the input XML. The `//` at the start of the `select` attribute means that it can match anywhere within the document, not just at the current level.

It then simply uses `copy-of` to insert the entirety of the node found in the `for-each`.